# How to make Qt delegate editors 'sticky'

Tags: c++, user-interface, delegates, qt4, qabstractitemmodel

I'm migrating an application from a homegrown UI to Qt. One of the most important controls is the property panel, which takes an object that implements my reflection API's interface and spits out a dialog box containing editors for all the properties.

I've written an implementation of `QAbstractItemModel` for my property system and I've written a few handlers for various types inside of a `QTableView`. I've also written a `QItemDelegate` to create editors for the properties.

The trouble is that I'd like the editors to hang around, rather than be strictly popups. This is so that they can handle the rendering of the property, require less clicks to operate and also not disappear as soon as something else gets the focus, such as my colour button - the editor (which has the slots listening for colour changes) disappears as soon as the colour picker dialog appears, which means that nothing is then listening for changes.

I can't find any options for making the editors persist. Am I barking up the wrong tree here or is there a more appropriate way of doing this? I've tried to do things the 'Qt' way but I'm already hitting brick walls.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [QAbstractItemView::openPersistentEditor()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#openPersistentEditor) method.